# How to create .NET independent apps using Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, unmanaged

There exist many C++ IDEs. However, I find Visual Stuido (Visual Studio 2010 Pro) the most comfortable maybe because I've spent a lot of time with it. The problem is I really don't like .NET dependent products both speed-wise and compatibility-wise.

I guess there is no way to compile VB and C# codes without .NET dependency (please correct me if I'm wrong). In C++, is there a way to use VS IDE with all its functions like auto-complete, GUI design etc.. while keeping all the codes unmanaged so that .NET will not be required?

Comment: Create a Win32 project? They are unmanaged C++ projects.

Comment: You can most certainly make C++ programs without using .NET in VisualStudio (I do it myself, using raw Win32 for both console and GUI apps). However, I can't tell you whether one of the many Microsoft class libraries has a graphical UI design tool in Visual Studio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a new project, if you select a Win32 project then it is a 'native' C++ application and does not depend on .NET.  For existing projects, the relevant setting is `Configuration Properties -> General -> Common Language Runtime Support`.  Set this to `No Common Language Runtime Support` to remove .NET dependencies.

Of course, the main UI designers for VC++ are the WPF and Windows.Forms designers - which depend on .NET components to implement them.  If you don't want to use them, you're stuck using MFC for your user interface.  It's not my idea of a good time, but many people do use it.

Comment: I had some strange .net error: Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application, so this fix my problem :)